# How to split time series?

Tags: time-series

```
sp500const = {"IBM", "GLD", "XOM", "AAPL"};
sp500ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData[#, "Close", DatePlus[-SampleSize]]] & /@ sp500const;
alloc = Table[N[1/Length[sp500const]], {i, Length[sp500const]}];
portfolio = TimeSeriesThread[alloc.# &, sp500ts]
```

There are 1722 data points of data set "portfolio", how can I split the data evenly. e.g 100 days per list and the final list should contain 22 days. Please feel to comment and advise. Thank you.

Comment: Would [`TimeSeriesWindow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesWindow.html) work for you? See also the examples in [Extract Part of a Time Series](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/time-series/extract-part-of-a-time-series.html).

Comment: I tried, but the length of data is changing everyday. I would find a method to split the list dynamically. Moreover, would you advise me how to know the date of 100th item. I tried the method DatePlus[portfolio["FirstDate"], 100], unfortunately, the date is not same as the date in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `Partition` with an [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html) length specification.

Get some data to play with:

```
series = TimeSeries@FinancialData["GE", {{2015, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}];
DateListPlot[series]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `Normal` to extract the time series data as a regular list; split the list using `Partition` into sub-lists of length up to $100$ elements (notice [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html)); then reconstitute each split list into a `TimeSeries` object:

```
TimeSeries /@ Partition[Normal@series, UpTo[100]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can check that the data represents the same span as the starting set:

```
DateListPlot@%
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use partition and get the error "TemporalData::argt: TemporalData called with 0 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.". Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @NelsonMok Did you use `Normal` on your series before / within `Partition`? Partition won't work on a `TimeSeries` object directly. Take a look at the example code in my answer.

Comment: @MacroB No, I didn't. I used a lot of list manipulation but they didn't work for timeseries. Thank you very much.